# Primefaces 2 MenuItem Action, ActionExpression or ActionListener

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have an existing working Primefaces 2 MenuBar with the MenuItems defined as follows:

```
<p:menubar style="width:625px" autoSubmenuDisplay="true">
    <p:submenu label="#{messages.label_home}">       
        <p:menuitem value="#{messages.label_logout}" url="#" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-close"/>
    </p:submenu>

    <p:submenu label="#{messages.label_cockpit}">
        <p:menuitem value="#{messages.label_create}" action="#{cockpitMenuBean.displayCreateDialog}" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-document" ajax="false"/>
        <p:menuitem value="#{messages.label_list}" action="#{cockpitMenuBean.displayList}" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-folder-open" ajax="false"/>
    </p:submenu>
```

I want to move the menu model from the xhtml to a backing bean as follows:

```
<p:menubar style="width:625px" autoSubmenuDisplay="true" model="#{cockpitMenuBean.menuModel}"/>
```

The problem and my question is centered on the `action` attribute above.

The CockpitMenuBean.displayCreateDialog() returns a string

```
public String displayCreateDialog() {
    cockpitMenu = new CockpitMenu();
    createDialogVisible = true;
    return "cockpitMenu";
}
```

`menuItem.setAction(arg);` which seemed like it should be the same as the `action` attribute in the XHTML is looking for arg to be a `MethodBinding` which is deprecated.

`menuItem.setActionExpression(arg)` is next most likely since the string in the XHTML is an EL expression `#{cockpitMenuBean.displayCreateDialog}`, but that just returns a String.

`menuItem.setActionListener(arg)` is deprecated.

I am not connecting the dots in moving from the XHTML to the backing bean in building the menuitems that correspond.

I tried:

```
MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem();
item1.setValue("Should be first");
item1.setUrl("#");
MethodExpression aEx = expFact.createMethodExpression(elCtx, "#{cockpitMenuBean.displayCreateDialog}", String.class, new Class[0]);
item1.setActionExpression(aEx);
menuModel.addMenuItem(item1);
```

And the menu item displays but nothing happens when I select it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you dynamically create an instance of [`UIInput`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html) or [`UICommand`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UICommand.html), then you should give the component a fixed ID. The PrimeFaces `MenuItem` extends `UICommand`.

So, this should do:

```
item1.setId("item1");
```